# Word Find and replace paragraph marks when there are tables

Tags: microsoft-word, find, replacement

Find and replace for paragraph marks doesn't work when there are tables in the document.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code, when run twice does what is needed. The replace feature, by itself, cannot handle this, never could.

Note the warnings in the MVP Page on [Remove All Empty Paragraphs](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DeleteEmptyParas.htm) that this will merge two tables separated only by a paragraph return.

```vb
Sub ReplaceEmptyParagraphs()
' https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DeleteEmptyParas.htm
' compiled from above by Charles Kenyon

'   IN GENERAL - EMPTY PARAGRAPHS
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^13{2,}"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    '   FIRST AND LAST EMPTY PARAGRAPHS
    Dim MyRange As range
    Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).range
    If MyRange.Text = vbCr Then MyRange.Delete

    Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.range
    If MyRange.Text = vbCr Then MyRange.Delete

    '   BEFORE AND AFTER TABLES
    Dim oTable As Table

    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        #If VBA6 Then
            'The following is only compiled and run if Word 2000 or 2002 is in use
            'It speeds up the table and your code
            oTable.AllowAutoFit = False
        #End If

        'Set a range to the para following the current table
        Set MyRange = oTable.range
        MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        'if para after table empty, delete it
        If MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Text = vbCr Then
            MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Delete
        End If

        'Set a range to the para preceding the current table
        Set MyRange = oTable.range
        MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        MyRange.Move wdParagraph, -1
        'if para before table empty, delete it
        If MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Text = vbCr Then
            MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Delete
        End If
    Next oTable
    Set MyRange = Nothing
    Set oTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

[Installing macros from forums](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm) by Graham Mayor

Comment: Hi Charles, again:
Indeed, your code changes two paragraph marks for one, but when there are many in a row you have to repeat the process several times, this is avoided by my code. So that you do not get an error, you must replace the semicolon with the comma.
In any case, neither one nor the other works when there are tables in the document. They do not remove the empty paragraphs before and after the table.

Comment: It is possible this can be reached by a macro that does not rely on the Replace feature. I have cross-posted this in the Microsoft Answers Community. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/find-and-replace-empty-paragraphs-when-tables-are/1133f52a-0052-49fd-8aa3-226a42e5999c

Comment: Thank you very much Charles:
He imagined a paragraph mark before and after the table, but was unaware that it did not remove the last two paragraph marks.

Comment: I completely rewrote my answer with a compilation of code from Dave Rado's MVP page: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DeleteEmptyParas.htm

Comment: Oddly, if you do 2 wildcard find and replaces - the first one for ^13{2,} and replace with nothing but a highlight colour; then do a second one for * with highlighting and replace with nothing/no formatting (this is assuming nothing else in your document is highlighted), it'll remove paragraphs around tables.